# Why say tachanun in selichos but not in davenning when say a sandek is in Shul?

Tags: halacha, tefilla, selichot, tachanun

If someone (eg *sandek, mohel*) is in Shul (the synagogue) whose presence stops the *kehillo* (congregation) saying *tachanun*, why is it that we do say *tachanun* in *Selichos* but not in *davenning* (the prayer service)?

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/83852

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no connection between Tachanun in Selichos to the regular Tachanun, as you can see that on Erev Rosh HaShana we say Tachanun in Selichos, yet we do not say Tachanun in Davening. The Tachanun we say by Davening is not said when there is a Sandek or mohel in the Shul, yet the Tachanun we say in Selichos, which has nothing to do with the Tachanun in Davening is said when there is a Sandak or Mohel in Shul.

Comment: Agreed. But what is it about the Tachanun in Selichos that makes it special? Is it, as I saw somewhere (where?) that Selichos is a different "species" than Tefilloh and the exemptions only apply to Tefilloh. Do you know any relevant sources please?

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok I think Beurei Hatefilah addresses the origin of tachanun as part of Selichot, in one of its articles. I'll see if I can locate it. Most likely, it's in the High Holiday section.