# Saying tachanun on a fast day when there is a chatan

Tags: marriage, fast-days, tachanun, selichot

Tachanun is not said when there is a Chatan in the minyan. However, on a fast day, Tachanun is usually said with Selichot. So if there is a chatan in a minyan on a fast day, would you say Selichot without tachanun?

Comment: related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10555/759

Comment: https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%A8%D7%A1%D7%94_%D7%99%D7%92

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mishnah Berurah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=25) commentary on O.C. 131:5 comment #27, if a chattan is in shul on a fast day, they say Selichot, but do **not** say Tachanun.